# How to use multiple statements in Ansible azure_rm conditional_groups

Tags: ansible, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm

I have an ansible role which pulls all VM names(Adding details below):

> plugin: azure_rm
>
> auth_source: cli
>
> include_vm_resource_groups:
>
> plain_host_names: yes
>
> conditional_groups:
> prod_hosts: "'prod1' in name"
> uat_hosts: "'uat' in name"

The above works perfectly fine. However, I have a requirement where the prod hosts can either have prod1 or prod2 in VM name. Ex: prod1-appvm, prod2-appvm. If I add "'prod1' or 'prod2' in name", will it work?

Ex:

> conditional_groups:
> prod_hosts: "'prod1' or 'prod2' in name"
> uat_hosts: "'uat' in name"

I tried searching online, and I found [this](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/%7Ekauffman/brocade/icx/ansible_modules/plugins/inventory/azure_rm.html), where it says a mapping of group names to Jinja2 expressions. But I couldn't get any confirmed answer if 'or' will work.

Thanks and Regards,

Safi Junaid.

Answer (score 0):

Add conditional statement using **When Condition** . When condition is used to control whether a task or role runs or is skipped.

It is the simplest conditional statement applies to a single task in Ansible. Create the task, then add a `when` statement that applies a test. You can write something as follows :

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
      when: name in ['prod1','prod2']
```

Check [this document](https://riptutorial.com/ansible/example/12269/when-condition) for examples on grouping VMs based on VM type.

Open this [Conditionals](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#basic-conditionals-with-when) document for more information.

Comment: Hi Saurav,

I think this will work only if the VM name is prod1, and not when prod1 is part of VM name. i..e this will work if VM name is "prod1" and not when VM name is "prod1-appvm". Correct me if am wrong?

Comment: You can use `when: "name.startswith('prod1')"` . You can combine logical operators as well like **and** and **or**. You can also try `when: name is match("prod1.*")`